# Pythonic improvements to object retrieval and more

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm the maintainer of https://github.com/servian/aws-auto-cleanup. I'm by no means a Python expert and hence I'd say I'm way off creating code that would be considered Pythonic. I do however love to tweak and improve code quality where I can.

I'd love for someone to check over a single class of mine and provide some tips where I could improve.

A simple class to look at is:

```
import sys

import boto3

from src.helper import Helper


class AmplifyCleanup:
    def __init__(self, logging, whitelist, settings, execution_log, region):
        self.logging = logging
        self.whitelist = whitelist
        self.settings = settings
        self.execution_log = execution_log
        self.region = region

        self._client_amplify = None
        self._dry_run = self.settings.get("general", {}).get("dry_run", True)

    @property
    def client_amplify(self):
        if not self._client_amplify:
            self._client_amplify = boto3.client("amplify", region_name=self.region)
        return self._client_amplify

    def run(self):
        self.apps()

    def apps(self):
        """
        Deletes Amplify Apps.
        """

        self.logging.debug("Started cleanup of Amplify Apps.")

        clean = (
            self.settings.get("services", {})
            .get("amplify", {})
            .get("app", {})
            .get("clean", False)
        )
        if clean:
            try:
                resources = self.client_amplify.list_apps().get("apps")
            except:
                self.logging.error("Could not list all Amplify Apps.")
                self.logging.error(sys.exc_info()[1])
                return False

            ttl_days = (
                self.settings.get("services", {})
                .get("amplify", {})
                .get("app", {})
                .get("ttl", 7)
            )

            for resource in resources:
                resource_id = resource.get("name")
                resource_app_id = resource.get("appId")
                resource_date = resource.get("updateTime")
                resource_action = None

                if resource_id not in self.whitelist.get("amplify", {}).get("app", []):
                    delta = Helper.get_day_delta(resource_date)

                    if delta.days > ttl_days:
                        try:
                            if not self._dry_run:
                                self.client_amplify.delete_app(appId=resource_app_id)
                        except:
                            self.logging.error(
                                f"Could not delete Amplify App '{resource_id}'."
                            )
                            self.logging.error(sys.exc_info()[1])
                            resource_action = "ERROR"
                        else:
                            self.logging.info(
                                f"Amplify App '{resource_id}' was last modified {delta.days} days ago "
                                "and has been deleted."
                            )
                            resource_action = "DELETE"
                    else:
                        self.logging.debug(
                            f"Amplify App '{resource_id}' was last modified {delta.days} days ago "
                            "(less than TTL setting) and has not been deleted."
                        )
                        resource_action = "SKIP - TTL"
                else:
                    self.logging.debug(
                        f"Amplify App '{resource_id}' has been whitelisted and has not been deleted."
                    )
                    resource_action = "SKIP - WHITELIST"

                Helper.record_execution_log_action(
                    self.execution_log,
                    self.region,
                    "Amplify",
                    "App",
                    resource_id,
                    resource_action,
                )

            self.logging.debug("Finished cleanup of Amplify Apps.")
            return True
        else:
            self.logging.info("Skipping cleanup of Amplify Apps.")
            return True
```

All my classes are basically the same general template calling different AWS Boto3 APIs. Hence if I can improve one, I can improve all of them.

My main dislikes are my dictionary retrievals:

```
clean = (
    self.settings.get("services", {})
    .get("amplify", {})
    .get("app", {})
    .get("clean", False)
)
```

and

```
ttl_days = (
    self.settings.get("services", {})
    .get("amplify", {})
    .get("app", {})
    .get("ttl", 7)
)
```

Should I be moving these to functions that I would call or should I do something else?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Code Review!

As this is an open source project, some guidelines/maintenance rules might take precedence over the suggestions here. However, a few points I'd like to mention:

1. Subclassing your cleanups. Looking through [the project source](https://github.com/servian/aws-auto-cleanup/tree/master/app/src), I notice that all AWS/boto3 supported classes have their own duplicates of `__init__`, with very minimal changes (like referencing a resource instead of low-level client). Using a base class which does a majority of this work for you would probably be more maintainable.
2. Naming of certain methods appears counter-intuitive. For example, the function `apps()` should actually read `cleanup_apps()`?
3. As you pointed out in the question itself, your primary concern is with the nested dictionary retrievals. Looking at the source, I notice that again, all looks are always from the `self.settings` dictionary. Perhaps a helper method in parent class (or extracted into the `Helper` class) could keep it smaller:

   ```py
   def setting_lookup(self, path, default=None):
       result = self.settings
       for key in path.split("."):
           result = result.get(key)
           if result is None:
               return default
       return result
   ```

   and the call would be (aws doesn't allow `/` and `.` in their resource names):

   ```py
   clean = self.settings_lookup("services.amplify.app.clean", default=False)
   ```

   If you think that the `jq` like lookup is not for you, it can be just sent across as list of consecutive keys.
4. The current system does not account for paginated results from [the `list_apps`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/amplify.html#Amplify.Client.list_apps) method. From the official docs, a default maximum is 100 resources in an API call, however for cleaning up of more resources, there is no pagination support in the `apps()` method for the cleanup class.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I don't see much needed change except those dict look-ups you complained about.

Observe that whenever any key in the `get` chain is missing, the last default will be returned. So you can safely convert that chain to a `try/except` structure and use the last default value in case of a missing key.

For example:

```py
clean = (
    self.settings.get("services", {})
    .get("amplify", {})
    .get("app", {})
    .get("clean", False)
)
```

Will be equivalent to:

```py
try:
    clean = self.settings["services"]["amplify"]["app"]["clean"]
except KeyError:
    clean = False
```